# java manifest.mf , how can I mean parent folder in Class-Path?

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf, packing

For example, my jar file is at somewhere/aaa/a.jar,and I want add somewhere/bbb/b.jar into Class-Path, how shall I do?

Relative path.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: and for your question, see [Jar File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath)

Comment: @Carlos thanks, know it is not possible now

Comment: Grammar; layout.